# error webscraping supermercado de alimentos chile

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

el principal problema es que no me esta dando el valor que le estoy pidiendo que es el "titulo" y "precio" que busco para lograr seguir un proyecto, porfavor ayuda

codigo base :

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url = 'https://www.jumbo.cl/leche-entera-colun-caja-1-l-natural/p'

page = requests.get(url)
soup_jumbo =  BeautifulSoup(page.content, 'html.parser')

titulo = soup_jumbo.find(id ="product-name").get_text()
precio = soup_jumbo.find(id ="price-best").get_text()

print(titulo)
print(precio)
```

no me arroja el precio que busco  :

```
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'get_text'
```

Comment: Tu problema es diferente, se origina por que el html que se te retorna no es el mismo que el de la pagina que ves en el navegador. Imprime la variable que contiene el html así `print(soup_jumbo)` y  verás que es totalmente diferente

Comment: @Christian lo puse en el codigo y me sigue saliendo lo mismo AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'getText'

Comment: tu error es otro! primero tienes que hacer que la petición te devuelva el mismo html que ves en el navegador ya que es totalmente diferente al que recibes con python.

Comment: @Christian y como puedo hacer esa petición es que me cuesta demasiado he intentado muchas cosas. gracias !

Comment: La verdad no sé, deberías editar tu pregunta para centrarla en el error original y  así otros te puedan ayudar

Comment: @Nacho La página que intentas descargar solo te muestra su contenido si es capaz de ejecutar javascript.  El método que utilizas no lo soporta y por eso no encuentra nada y te da esos errores.  Busca la forma de scrappear páginas con javascript, investiga, experimenta, y cuando lo tengas más claro, si aun así te surge algun error, formula una nueva pregunta y a ver si alguien sabe ayudarte en tu error concreto, estudiado e investigado por tu parte.

Comment: gracias @masterguru

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Como mencioné en mi comentario todo se origina por que el html devuelto no es el mismo que el que vez en la página, pues al imprimirlo se observa algo como esto(se ha omitido gran parte del html para que la respuesta pueda ser publicada):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html lang="es">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8"/>
<meta content="width=device-width,initial-scale=1,shrink-to-fit=no" name="viewport"/>
<meta content="#1fa02e" name="theme-color"/>
<link href="/manifest.json" rel="manifest"/>
<link href="https://assets.jumbo.cl/favicon/favicon-512.png" rel="icon" sizes="512x512" type="image/png"/>
<link href="https://assets.jumbo.cl/favicon/apple-touch-icon-60.png" rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="60x60"/>
<link href="https://assets.jumbo.cl/favicon/apple-touch-icon-72.png" rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="72x72"/>
<link href="https://assets.jumbo.cl/favicon/apple-touch-icon-144.png" rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="144x144"/>
<link href="https://assets.jumbo.cl/favicon/apple-touch-icon-152.png" rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="152x152"/>
<link href="https://assets.jumbo.cl/favicon/favicon-128.png" rel="icon" sizes="128x128"/>
<link href="https://assets.jumbo.cl/favicon/favicon-192.png" rel="icon" sizes="192x192"/>
<link href="https://assets.jumbo.cl/favicon/favicon.ico" rel="shortcut icon" type="image/x-icon"/>
<meta content="#1fa02e" name="msapplication-TileColor"/>
<meta content="https://assets.jumbo.cl/favicon/mstile-310.png" name="msapplication-square310x310logo"/>
<meta content="https://assets.jumbo.cl/favicon/mstile-150.png" name="msapplication-square150x150logo"/>
<meta content="https://assets.jumbo.cl/favicon/mstile-144.png" name="msapplication-TileImage"/>
<meta content="https://assets.jumbo.cl/favicon/mstile-70.png" name="msapplication-square70x70logo"/>
<title>Leche entera 1 L | Jumbo.cl</title>
<style>body{display: none;}</style>
<link href="https://assets.jumbo.cl/824d82ecf0c0e3068ad1-styles.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<body>
<meta content="Leche entera 1 L | Jumbo.cl" property="og:title">
<meta content="Encuentra Leche entera Colun 1 L y la mejor variedad de productos Colun en Jumbo.cl" property="og:description">
<meta content="https://cl-jumboweb-front-render.smdigital.cl/leche-entera-colun-caja-1-l-natural/p" property="og:url">
<meta content="https://jumbo.vteximg.com.br/arquivos/ids/396670/Leche-entera-1-L.jpg?v=637469297528530000" property="og:image">
<meta content="product" property="og:type">
<meta content="230229067365496" property="fb:app_id">
<meta content="Leche entera 1 L | Jumbo.cl" property="twitter:title">
<meta content="@JumboChile" property="twitter:site">
<meta content="https://jumbo.vteximg.com.br/arquivos/ids/396670/Leche-entera-1-L.jpg?v=637469297528530000" property="twitter:image">
<meta content="Encuentra Leche entera Colun 1 L y la mejor variedad de productos Colun en Jumbo.cl" property="twitter:description">
<meta content="Encuentra Leche entera Colun 1 L y la mejor variedad de productos Colun en Jumbo.cl" name="description"/>
<meta content="@JumboChile" name="twitter:site"/>
<meta content="https://jumbo.vteximg.com.br/arquivos/ids/396670/Leche-entera-1-L.jpg?v=637469297528530000" name="twitter:image"/>
<meta content="Encuentra Leche entera Colun 1 L y la mejor variedad de productos Colun en Jumbo.cl" name="twitter:description"/>
<meta content="summary" name="twitter:card"/><meta content="Colun" property="product:brand"/>
<meta content="799" property="product:price:amount"/>
<meta content="in stock" property="product:availability"/>
<meta content="6697" property="product:retailer_item_id"/>
<meta content="new" property="product:condition"/>
<meta content="CLP" property="product:price:currency"/>
<noscript>
    You need to enable JavaScript to run this app.
</noscript>
<div id="root"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Incluso dice que para usar la pagina necesitamos de JavaScript, no sé si eso se pueda hacer solo con BeautifulSoup. Para salir del apuro puedes ver la estructura de esta respuesta, analizarla y obtener los datos que quieres.

Para acceder a los atributos de las etiquetas debemos especificarle al método `find` que queremos acceder a dichos atributos, eso se hace especificando el parámetro `attr` y pasándole un diccionario que especifica que la etiqueta debe contener un atributo y valor específico.

```py
titulo = soup_jumbo.find(attrs={"property":"twitter:title"}).get_attribute_list("content", "")
precio = soup_jumbo.find(attrs={"property":"product:price:amount"})

print(titulo)
print(precio)
```

Comment: muchas gracias, como obtuviste toda esa información es posible que me expliques eso para hacerlo con otra pagina? muchas gracias !

Comment: pues haciendo `print(soup_jumbo)` y viendo si en eso estaba la información que se necesitaba

Comment: pero pongo abajo del programa print(soup_jumbo) nomas?

Comment: sip, eso te mostrará el contenido de la variable

Comment: gracias amigo, solo otra consulta ahora obtuve lo siguiente :                                           ['Leche entera 1 L | Jumbo.cl']
<meta content="799" property="product:price:amount"/>     como puedo hacer que se vea mas ordenado ? asi como : leche entera 1l -  799 pesos

Comment: vote positiva tu pregunta para que puedas entrar a [este chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/133107/ayuda-d) y podamos hablar mejor.